# How can I set a use a frame in tkinter multiple times with different variables?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I am not sure if I am asking the right question here, so please correct me if I am not. I wish to optimize my program from this:

```
    #Podzol - MCPE, PC
    class mc_podzol(tk.Frame):

        #Initialize
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            mc_podzol.configure(self, background = backgroundColor)

            #Item Info
            text_file = open("C:/Program Files/iNTMI/assets/descriptions/minecraft_podzol.txt", "r")
            file = text_file.read()
            text_file.close()

            #Setups
            itemLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Minecraft - Podzol", font = LARGE_FONT)
            itemIdLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Item IDs ~ 3:2 ~ minecraft:dirt:2", font = NORMAL_FONT)
            itemInfo = ttk.Label(self, text = file, font = LARGE_FONT)
            exitButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Menu", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(itemsPage1))

            #Placement
            itemLabel.pack(pady = 10)
            itemIdLabel.pack()
            itemInfo.pack(pady = 5)

            exitButton.pack()

    #Cobblestone - MCPE, PC, Console
    class mc_cstone(tk.Frame):

        #Initialize
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            mc_cstone.configure(self, background = backgroundColor)

            #Item Info
            text_file = open("C:/Program Files/iNTMI/assets/descriptions/minecraft_cstone.txt", "r")
            file = text_file.read()
            text_file.close()

            #Setups
            itemLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Minecraft - Podzol", font = LARGE_FONT)
            itemIdLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Item IDs ~ 4 ~ minecraft:cobblestone", font = NORMAL_FONT)
            itemInfo = ttk.Label(self, text = file, font = LARGE_FONT)
            exitButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Menu", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(itemsPage1))

            #Placement
            itemLabel.pack(pady = 10)
            itemIdLabel.pack()
            itemInfo.pack(pady = 5)

            exitButton.pack()

    #Wood Planks - MCPE, PC, Console
    class mc_woodplanks(tk.Frame):

        #Initialize
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            mc_woodplanks.configure(self, background = backgroundColor)

            #Item Info
            text_file = open("C:/Program Files/iNTMI/assets/descriptions/minecraft_woodplanks.txt", "r")
            file = text_file.read()
            text_file.close()

            #Setups
            itemLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Minecraft - Wood Planks", font = LARGE_FONT)
            itemIdLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Item IDs ~ 5 ~ minecraft:planks", font = NORMAL_FONT)
            itemInfo = ttk.Label(self, text = file, font = LARGE_FONT)
            exitButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Menu", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(itemsPage1))

            #Placement
            itemLabel.pack(pady = 10)
            itemIdLabel.pack()
            itemInfo.pack(pady = 5)

            exitButton.pack()

    #Saplings - MCPE, PC, Console
    class mc_saplings(tk.Frame):

        #Initialize
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            mc_woodplanks.configure(self, background = backgroundColor)

            #Item Info
            text_file = open("C:/Program Files/iNTMI/assets/descriptions/minecraft_sapling.txt", "r")
            file = text_file.read()
            text_file.close()

            #Setups
            itemLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Minecraft - Saplings", font = LARGE_FONT)
            itemIdLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Item IDs ~ 6 ~ minecraft:sapling", font = NORMAL_FONT)
            itemInfo = ttk.Label(self, text = file, font = LARGE_FONT)
            exitButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Menu", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(itemsPage2))

            #Placement
            itemLabel.pack(pady = 10)
            itemIdLabel.pack()
            itemInfo.pack(pady = 5)

            exitButton.pack()

    #Bedrock - MCPE, PC, Console
    class mc_bedrock(tk.Frame):

        #Initialize
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            mc_woodplanks.configure(self, background = backgroundColor)

            #Item Info
            text_file = open("C:/Program Files/iNTMI/assets/descriptions/minecraft_bedrock.txt", "r")
            file = text_file.read()
            text_file.close()

            #Setups
            itemLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Minecraft - Bedrock", font = LARGE_FONT)
            itemIdLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Item IDs ~ 7 ~ minecraft:bedrock", font = NORMAL_FONT)
            itemInfo = ttk.Label(self, text = file, font = LARGE_FONT)
            exitButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Menu", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(itemsPage2))

            #Placement
            itemLabel.pack(pady = 10)
            itemIdLabel.pack()
            itemInfo.pack(pady = 5)

            exitButton.pack()
```

to something like this:

```
    class mc_description(tk.Frame):

            #Initialize
            def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

                global itemDescription

                mc_description.configure(self, background = backgroundColor)

                #Item Info
                text_file = open(itemDescription, "r")
                file = text_file.read()
                text_file.close()

                #Setups
                itemLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = itemName, font = LARGE_FONT)
                itemIdLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = itemID, font = NORMAL_FONT)
                itemInfo = ttk.Label(self, text = file, font = LARGE_FONT)

                exitButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Menu", command = (combine_funcs(button_sound, self.destroy, lambda: controller.show_frame(itemsPage1))))

                #Placement
                itemLabel.pack(pady = 10)
                itemIdLabel.pack()
                itemInfo.pack(pady = 5)

                exitButton.pack()
```

I wish to set the variables in a separate .py file and use the mc_description for every item. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what variables do you want to set in a separate .py file?

Comment: @BryanOakley I wish to set itemName, itemID, and itemDescription.

Comment: One all the variables needed to create an `mc_description` instance are defined. You need to modify the class `__init__()` constructor to accept these them as arguments which are used immediately or to create instance attributes if they'll be needed after construction. Once that is done, you can put the various combinations in a data structure of some sort defined in .py module and import it as need. The module can also have functions to access the data structure if desired. You might also want to consider putting them instead in an .ini file and reading it with the `ConfigParser` module.

Comment: @martineau Can you explain that a bit more please? I'm still learning Python and that doesn't make much sense to me.